# Consuming IBM websphere MQ V.8 in .net application

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I want to create an application that will consume  websphere MQ in .net.  I have created the **QueueManager , local Queue and Channels**  but i am getting **MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME** error.  But i am facing error while connecting to **MQQueueManager** . Below is my code`

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
    const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;

    // Define the name of the queue manager to use (applies to all connections)
    const String qManager = "QM1";

    // Define the name of your host connection (applies to client connections only)
    const String hostName = "aspireggn69(1415)";

    // Define the name of the channel to use (applies to client connections only)
    const String channel = "QM2Q2";



    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Accept();
    }


    static Hashtable init(String connectionType)
    {
        Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();

        // Add the connection type
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);

        // Set up the rest of the connection properties, based on the
        // connection type requested
        switch (connectionType)
        {
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS:
                break;
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT:
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT:
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED:
                connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
                connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
                break;
        }

        return connectionProperties;
    }


    public void Accept()
    {
        try
        {
            Hashtable connectionProperties = init(connectionType);

           ## Here I am getting error ##
            **MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);**
        }
        catch (MQException ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}`
```

I am not sure which channel type i need to create for consuming messages in Websphere MQ. Any help is much appreciated.
[Below is snapshot of channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BCPS.png)
Thanks

Comment: You need a server connection channel to connect remote applications to the QM. Applications running on the same server as the QM don't need a channel, but need to use connection type bindings.

Comment: Are you sure that `QM2Q2` is a proper client channel?

Comment: Attila Repasi  : Thanx for your prompt reply.  I have created channel as Server Connection and Queue as local queue. But my channel always show inactive even i start it by right clicking on it. I am using  MQ explorer for it . Is there any link or article that tell how to consume websphere MQ V.8 in .net step by step ??  I have tried this link but its not working http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-quick-start-with-C-Sharp-and-websphere-mq/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a server connection(SVRCONN) channel on the queue manager. You can either use MQExplorer or MQSC Shell to create the channel. If you are using MQSC - run command

`DEFINE CHANNEL (QM2Q2) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)`.

This is simplest form but is enough to start with.

After that you need to configure authority to connect to queue manager and work with the queues. Look [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/getting_going_without_turning_off_mq_security?lang=en) for help.

Comment: In light of the OP's question, the channel name in this example won't work.

Comment: @shashi : Thanx for your reply. I have created server connection(SVRCONN) channel and local queue  and i am using MQExplorer . I have added current user to MQM group and added username in MCA attribute of channel. It always show inactive status even i have started it. I  have taken reference of http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-quick-start-with-C-Sharp-and-websphere-mq/  but  it is giving me 2035 error code .

Comment: Thanks Morag. I was hoping @Naveen would change the name.

Comment: The channel would go into Running once an application connects to queue manager. Check the queue manager error logs for more details on what user id is queue manager is receiving.

Comment: Shashi :  I have updated the configurations .
            QueueName = "QMngr_Naveen.LOCAL.ONE";
           ChannelInfo = "QMngr_Naveen.SVRCONN/TCP/naveen-PC(1414)";

Comment: QueueManagerName = "QMngr_Naveen"    . I have checked the event logs. Below is the error.                                       User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe) Host(NAVEEN-PC) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(8.0.0.5) QMgr(QMngr_Naveen)

Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'naveen'.  

The call to initialize the User ID 'naveen' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.

Comment: One thing i want to confirm . I am creating  Queue Manager with New Option . Is this correct or shall i use Add Remote Queue Manager menu for creating Queue Manager ?

Comment: Add Remote Queue Manager menu can be used for administering an existing queue manager running on different machine.